# how to color specific data table cells in r shiny data table

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, shiny

I have a data table created from a dataframe like this :

```
output$main_temp <- renderDataTable(df[,-1:-1], width = "auto")
```

I would like to color with and without values. Cells with values with green and without values to red.

I tried :

```
output$main_temp <- renderDataTable({
datatable(df[,-1:-1], options = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(targets = 6, visible = FALSE))
)) %>% formatStyle(
  names(df[,-1:-1]),
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
)
})
```

Sample data :

[image: Sample data]

Required output:

[image: output]

Comment: Can you give example of data? It's hard to guess how *no values* look in your original data.

Comment: data is taken from a csvfle.. no dat is blank data...nothing will be shown

Answer (score 5):

`styleEqual` maps its arguemnts *one-to-one*:

> values:    a vector of CSS values
>
> levels: a character vector of data values to be mapped (one-to-one) to
>   CSS values

Therefore you could do

```
df <- data.frame(cat = letters[1:5], 
                 t1 = c(33, NA, 89, 45, NA),
                 t2 = c(NA, NA, 4, NA, 23),
                 t3 = c(56, NA, NA, 67, NA),
                 t4 = c(NA, NA, 12, 66, NA))

uval <- unique(df[!is.na(df)])
datatable(df) %>% 
    formatStyle(names(df)[-1], 
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(NA, uval), 
    c('red', rep('lightgreen', length(uval)))))
```

mapping each value to the same color.

[image]

Another option is to implement it *by hand* using JavaScript:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)

js <- 'function(settings, json) {
    // For every row, select all table cells starting at cell #3
    $("#DataTables_Table_0 td:nth-child(3+1n)").each(function(key, val) {
        if( $(this).html() == "") {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#f00");
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#0f0");
        };
    });
}'

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(dataTableOutput("main_temp")))

server <- function(input, output) {
    df <- data.frame(cat = letters[1:5], 
                     t1 = c(33, NA, 89, 45, NA),
                     t2 = c(NA, NA, 4, NA, 23),
                     t3 = c(56, NA, NA, 67, NA),
                     t4 = c(NA, NA, 12, 66, NA))
    // when the table has finished loading, execute the JS code
    output$main_temp <- renderDataTable(df, options = list(initComplete = JS(js)))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```